# Exclude specific directory from htaccess redirectmatch

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am migrating my blog from a subdirectory to the root of my domain, but I am leaving the admin panel in its current location, as such I need to do a 301 redirect for anything which matches the following path, except the "admin/" subdirectory.

I have the core redirect working with this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (^/oldblogpath/)(.*) http://www.example.com/$2
```

The path I want to exclude from the above is "/oldblogpath/admin/" - please help me understand what I'm missing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead pattern for this:

```bash
RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldblogpath/(?!admin/)(.*) http://www.example.com/$1
```

`(?!admin/)` is a negative lookahead condition that fails the match of `admin/` appears right after matching starting directory path.

Make sure to clear old browser cache completely before testing this change.